# Running React app in Docker container not running correctly

Tags: docker, create-react-app

I have a small React app that I would like to run in a Docker container. I have the following Dockerfile filled out like this:

```
# base image
FROM node:9.6.1

# set working directory
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package-lock.json /app/package-lock.json
COPY package.json /app/package.json

COPY . /app

RUN npm install

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

After doing a build, I was able to correctly (I think) create an image.

```
>docker image list
REPOSITORY           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
notes                latest              e4ccada07b84        18 hours ago        846MB
```

However, when I run on the image, it does run `npm start`, but not in the port I specified and if I go to the URL it provides it can't connect to anything.

```
>docker run -p 3030:3030  notes:latest

You can now view notes in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000/
  On Your Network:  http://172.17.0.4:3000/

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.
```

What am I missing to get this running in a container correctly?

Comment: Try to change the command to `docker run -p 3030:3000  notes:latest`

Comment: @Yuankun Unfortunately, that gives the same result as above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your React app is set to run on port 3000 of the container **and** since you mentioned you were going to the URL in the output; I'm assuming you're attempting to reach port 3000 of your host.

Change your command to the following; which will attach port 3000 of your host to port 3000 of the container.

```
docker container run -p 3000:3000 notes:latest
```

Then head on over to http://localhost:3000/ - unless you're using Docker Toolbox, in that case you'll want to use http://192.168.99.100:3000/

I'd also recommend adding an `EXPOSE 3000` into your `Dockerfile` as that is good practice.

Just a note - the `-p` flag uses `<host>:<container>` for the format.

Comment: That seemed to work! Does the `docker run` command do the same as `docker container run`?

Comment: Yes - the `docker container run` and `docker run` commands are the exact same; but as Docker has grown - and new commands have been added, Docker has decided to add it under a subcommand as well so the command list wasn't so lengthy.

Answer (score 0):

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -it image_name
```